# What's causing the overhead when running jobs in the background?

Tags: linux, bash, process, parallel-processing

As part of an attempt to speed up some CPU-intensive processing in a system, I'm looking to parallelize an expensive call to external binary.  There's much more overhead to running this binary in multiple processes than I expected and I'd like some help to figure out where it's coming from.

On an 8-core machine, when I run 6 calls to the binary sequentially with a loop in bash, it times like this:

```
real    0m7.034s
user    0m6.798s
sys     0m0.199s
```

When I do the same loop, but indicate to run the calls in the background with `&` followed by a `wait`, it times like this:

```
real    0m9.824s
user    0m54.048s
sys     0m0.458s
```

The binary reads a few unchanging data files 21M & 164K, then reads a single input file <1K, performs CPU-intensive computations, and writes results to stdout.  What could be providing enough overhead that it's slower to run these in parallel?

Here's the bash script I'm using to execute the calls in parallel.  For sequential behaviour it's the same except the if block is gone and the & is removed from the command.

```
SPAWN_COUNT=6
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6; do
    /opt/netMHCpan-2.8/netMHCpan /tmp/test_input -ic50 -a BoLA-D18.4 -l 10 > /dev/null &
    NPROC=$(($NPROC+1))
    if [ "$NPROC" -ge "$SPAWN_COUNT" ]; then
        wait
        NPROC=0
    fi
done
```

Comment: How much memory does it use? These symptoms look like it's thrashing.

Comment: Try running `vmstat 1` in another window while you perform the two tests.

Comment: How big are the files it's reading?

Comment: Can you show how you do the loop and no-loop scripts?

Comment: It doesn't look like memory usage is the issue, free memory before running the script was 12512256, and the lowest it reached while the script executed was 12277468.

Comment: The input file is 516 bytes, the data files I believe it is reading by default based on the command's output are 21M & 164K.

Comment: Running vmstat every second starting before the script and continuing after it results in this: https://dpaste.de/qQsP

Answer (score 0):

Divide the process into smaller parts.
Make each smaller part an executable file (even an script with `chmod u+x $script`) and measure the memory usage with time:

```
tf='wall:%e s:%S u:%U (%Xtext+%Ddata %F %p %t %Kmem %Mmax)'
/usr/bin/time -f "$tf" "$script"
```

That should let you find what is eating your memory (if any).

---

#### Edit:

The smaller process call reported this (with time):
wall:1.08 s:0.03 u:1.05 (0text+0data 0 0 0 0mem 11844max)  one instance
wall:8.89 s:0.41 u:48.93 (0text+0data 0 0 0 0mem 11848max) jobs in parallel

Memory was not a problem, using just 11.85 meg.

Using strace (strace -c script) revealed that there were calls to `wait()`, and that those were the ones eating most of the time. Not clear (as yet) why the old binary behaved like that.

I'll post more info as I get it.

Comment: wall:1.08 s:0.03 u:1.05 (0text+0data 0 0 0 0mem 11844max) for a single instance

Comment: wall:8.89 s:0.41 u:48.93 (0text+0data 0 0 0 0mem 11848max) running the jobs in parallel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93015/discussion-between-jivanamara-and-binaryzebra).